# How can I create SVN-compatible patches from Mercurial?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I am new to Mercurial and using hgsubversion. I have erred in using hg merge - I now know not to do this for next time but I now need to get my changes into SVN.

How do I create patches from Mercurial that are compatible with SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like once you have hgsubversion installed, you can just use a similar command:

```
hg diff --svn -r default
```

See more info [here](http://pythonwise.blogspot.com/2011/01/having-hg-output-svn-diffs.html).

Comment: I've hgsubversion installed but when I try that command I get the following error: `abort: hgsubversion metadata unavailable; please run 'hg svn rebuildmeta'`. Have I to do something else?